# Passwords (Bcrypt.Net) + WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, security

Let's say we have a client that connects to a server over WCF:

```
Server <---WCF---> Client
```

The user needs to log in via username + password.
What is the best practice to verify the password of the client?

Do I just hash the password at the client and send the hashed password over the wire, like this:

```
// client:    
return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(password, BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(xx));
```

Is there another way, because sending a password over the wire and hash it at the server doesn't look the smartest thing.
Is it ok to send a hash over the wire?

Comment: Let's say, someone stole the database, and therefore has complete access to all password hashes, and now he/she wants to impersonate someone. So he/she simply sends the hash to your server. That's a lot worse. So you need to trust that the transport protocol you're using is sufficiently secure, so that the hashing can take place on the server.

Comment: what is worse, getting the plaintext password or the hash? Because if that user is using the same password on different accounts...?

Comment: 1. Get servers public key to the client ([somehow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx)). 2. Encrypt (don't hash) client password with server public key. 3. Send encrypted password to server. 4. Decrypt with server private key. 5. Hash decrypted password and compare to stored hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... at least it's a common way. Anyway you should try to ensure that https is used to even be more secure...

Another possibility would be to use integrated security mechanisms provided by WCF [itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650862.aspx) .

EDIT: I would like to share the Credit with [@Corak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336590/corak) as he mentioned pulic key encription as a secure and smart way to handle this scenario.

Comment: We will secure the connection itself but the question is more about the actual data you share over the wire: is it better to send a hash or a password itself over the wire or something else?

Comment: In any case you should not send the passwort itself if there's another option. Hashing is a simple and (based on algorithm and salt) a valid approach. You could for example add the username to the salt to have a different hash for different users with the same passwort, ...
Many login mechanismns are using this method itself to store passwords to the database (together with other information). Another option would be to implement (or use) a more elaborated mechanismn like SASL, ... bot these would need more technology and might not work simple with WCF

Comment: Fully agree with using WCF integrated security mechanisms. Hashing itself only "works" if done server side for the reason stated in my other comment.

Comment: I've accepted this answer but the comment from @Corak helps a lot to get the public key and encrypt.

Comment: If you want to use a hashed auth, then you should use `Digest` authentication. Problem with Integrated Security is that it is very Windows-centric.